# Robot framework custom library selenium issue

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Do you know how to properly pass webdriver session to custom library in robot framework ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found solution

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


def TryToLoginWithInvalidCredentialls(signInButton):

    se2lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('Selenium2Library')
    driver = se2lib._current_browser()

    signIn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(signInButton)
    signIn.Click()
```